# Using countrypickerview ,I want to display only the phonecode not the flag in the left side of text field

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2, cocoapods, swift4.2

By default this library displays country flag, country code and phone code . I was able to remove the country code but not the flag .

```
Let cpv = CountryPickerview(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 120,height:20))
UserNumber.leftView =cpv
UserNumber.leftView =.always
cpv.showCountryCodeInView = false
```

Comment: Add link to your library

Comment: It's  there right?

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet from storybaord, set width of the view equal to 50:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwCountryPicker: CountryPickerView!
```

and set following values:

```
    vwCountryPicker.flagSpacingInView = -30
    vwCountryPicker.flagImageView.isHidden = true
```